# Adding derived objects to a list dynamically

Tags: c#

I have an inheritance tree like so:

```
BaseType
TypeA : BaseType
TypeB : BaseType
TypeC : BaseType
```

Each derived object has a variable named `objectName` that defines that object's name.

I also have an array and a list that both hold the`BaseType` objects as well as any objects derived from `BaseType`. The array has objects stored in it upon being created, meanwhile the list is empty for future use:

```
BaseType[] arrayA = new BaseType[] { new TypeA(), new TypeB(), new TypeC(), }

List<BaseType> listA = new List<BaseType>;
```

I also have a method that is used to add an object that is in the array to the list:

```
public void AddToList(BaseType itemToAdd)
{
    if(itemToAdd.objectName == "Type A")
        {
        listA.Add(new TypeA());
    }
    else if(itemToAdd.objectName == "Type B")
        {
        listA.Add(new TypeB());
    }
    else if(itemToAdd.objectName == "Type C")
        {
        listA.Add(new TypeA());
    }
}
```

How can I avoid having to use all of those `if` commands? At one point I tried:

```
public void AddToList(BaseType itemToAdd)
{
    listA.Add( new itemToAdd());
}
```

Which did not work. So how can I go about doing something like this? The objects are constantly growing and I don't want to have to put an `if` for every derived object I add. I should also mention, not sure if this will have any bearing on the solution, I've been using folders to organize the .cs files. So I have all of the derived classes in a folder named "Types" so to create a new instance of that object I have to type:

```
listA.Add(new Types.TypeA());
```

Comment: What's wrong with just using: `listA.Add(itemToAdd);`? Is there some reason you need to create new objects before adding them to the list?

Answer (score 2):

well, the first thing I see is that you're instantiating your items, and not just passing the item in

are you trying to do the following?

```
public void AddToList(BaseType itemToAdd)
{
    listA.Add(itemToAdd);
}
```

the reason

```
public void AddToList(BaseType itemToAdd)
{
    listA.Add( new itemToAdd());
}
```

doesn't work is because `itemToAdd` is not a type, it's a variable of the type `BaseType`.  you can't use the `new` keyword on it.  it just doesn't make sense.

if you're trying to copy the item, you can do something like the following.

```
public void AddToList(BaseType itemToAdd)
{
    listA.Add(itemToAdd.Copy());
}
```

**You will have to write your own copy method for this part to work.**

Comment: More or less I believe I was under the assumption that I needed to add a create a new object to add to the list, because the list is actually in a completely separate object. Oh well I feel stupid sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @user1801065  You might want to google the difference between value types and reference types.  It's a fairly fundamental aspect of programming, and you'll keep running into theses issues if you don't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Why is your AddToList creating new objects instead of adding the itemToAdd? In other words:

```
public void AddToList(BaseType itemToAdd)
{
    listA.Add(itemToAdd);
}
```

Also, there is no need to have a string for the type of object. You can get the type of any object by using:

```
myObj.GetType();
```

And you can compare the type of an object using `typeof`:

```
if (myObj.GetType() == typeof(TypeA))
```

If you *really, really* must create new objects of the same type as `itemToAdd`, then you can use `Activator.CreateInstance` to avoid all those type checks:

```
listA.Add((BaseType)Activator.CreateInstance(itemToAdd.GetType());
```

But I suspect that isn't what you want to do anyway.

Comment: In your first code block you should remove the extra parentheses after `listA.Add(itemToAdd`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could make a factory to class to create the object you want based on the class type passed in and use it like this:

```
public void AddToList(BaseType itemToAdd)
{
    listA.Add(ItemFactory.Create(itemToAdd.objectName));
}
```

But of course, this just pushes the question down a level (but still improves the readability of the AddToList code).

To do what you're really asking requires, I think, either doing what you have already suggested: if-else chains (or a switch perhaps) to create an instance of the correct type; or using reflection to new up an instance of a dynamically chosen class.

As simple example:

```
BaseType Create(BaseType source)
{
    var constructor = source.GetType().GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
    return constructor.Invoke(new object[0]) as BaseType;
}
```